# Creating an Line chart with date in X axis in GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with three variables, date, and numeric format.

I am trying to draw a line chart with Xaxis as date and Y axis with Variable 2.

I tried the below code, but in X axis i could see the integers instead of dates.

```
dataframe <- data.frame(Var1, var2, var3)
var1 <- c("22.01.2018" , "10.01.2018", "2.02.2018", "01.03.2018")
var2 <- c("0.98", "0.05", "0.98", "0.51")
dataframe$var1 <- as.Date(dataframe$var1 , format = "%dd/%mm/%yyyy" )

# plotting the graph
ggplot(data=dataframe, aes(x=dataframe$var1, y=dataframe$var3, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()

ggplot(data=dataframe, aes(x=dataframe$dat1, y=dataframe$var3, group=1)) +
  geom_line(linetype="dashed") +
  geom_point()

ggplot(data=dataframe, aes(x=dataframe$dat1, y=dataframe$var3, group=1)) +
  geom_line(color="red") +
  geom_point()
```

when I check my var1, after converting to date format, I could see "22/01/20".

Could anyone help how i could plot with x axis in date format and y axis with var3?

Comment: There are several mistakes in your code: (1) get rid of the `dataframe$`-parts inside the `aes`; (2) you need `as.Date(dataframe$var1 , format = "%d.%m.%Y" )` to get `var1` in the date-format; (3) you might want to convert `var2` to a numeric variable with `as.numeric` and (4) you didn't define `var3`.

Comment: @Jaap ok will try this way.